# jQuery .post won't read PHP include

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, include

I built my website from bunch of php include files that work like a template. When I change something in one file whole website changes.

When I click on a radio button, ajax should activate and it should try to communicate with the other php file which should connect to the database and to send information back to the original page, but it can't connect to the database, since that file contains the php include function, and it would only work if I'd put content of that include file manually there. but it won't work if it put it like this

```
include("includes/connect.php");
```

and if I manually paste content into that file like this it will work

```
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("demo") or mysql_error();
```

is there a way to make it work with include function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've forgot that `include` has nothing to do with `client, javascript, post`.
You're probably including file from wrong folder. Try to change

```
include("includes/connect.php");
```

to

```
include(dirname(__FILE__)."/includes/connect.php");
```

and make sure that includes/connect.php exists

Comment: I agree, check ur file directory and make sure the file exist

Comment: To add to this: I find it easier to route all AJAX calls of any sort through a single handler file in the main directory you are currently accessing, then sending along the file location or extension you need as a parameter.  You'd then just `include $_POST['file']` with `$_POST['file']` being the file location or extension.  In this way, you can be sure you are always accessing the files in the correct area - that is if the file exists.

Comment: @Phillip and that's exactly why PHP has such a miserable security reputation. `include('/etc/passwd')` is such a nice thing to have happen to your server.

Comment: unbeleaveable.. i taught that jquery has a some kind of a conflict with php include function, but it hasnt, instead of that i accidently forgot something in mysql commands , and that was the reason why i didnt had valid response. Thanks for your help this answer of yours made me do some serious checks of my code, wich i was sure it was correct but it turned out it was not.

Comment: @Marc B Wouldn't bother me.  I have it do multiple security checks once the data arrives on both my handler page and the actual page.  Now maybe for someone who doesn't have any security in place, that would be a problem.  Facebook also helps greatly as I can crosscheck certain data with them (I mostly work on their canvas anyways).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use absolute path instead of relative path.
Try to change

```
include("includes/connect.php");
```

on

```
include(__DIR__ . "/includes/connect.php");
```

You should add /../../ near includes for getting right way.
If you use PHP5.2 instead of __DIR__ use dirname(__FILE__');